# Iptables v1.4.14: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, iptables

I'm trying to set iptable rules, and I got following error message when I use iptable :

```
iptables v1.4.14: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I'm using :

```
cat /etc/debian_version 
7.4

uname -a
Linux myserver 2.6.32-22-pve #1 SMP Mon Jul 15 08:36:46 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux

uname -r
2.6.32-22-pve
```

This is a virtual server hosted by a service provider.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Maybe your kernel was compiled without NAT support ? Does your service provider let you replace the kernel ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had the same problem and this worked:

```
sudo modprobe ip_tables
sudo echo 'ip_tables' >> /etc/modules
```

http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3196

Comment: For LXC/containers, you need to do this on the host since the containers can't load modules.

Answer (score 40):

I had the same problem with Debian 8. I fixed it by restarting the system. It seems that the error can occur if the kernel image was updated and the system was not restarted thereafter.

Comment: Same for Arch linux update that I just applied yesterday. Reboot/restart = success!

Comment: Same for Raspbian after a big `apt dist-upgrade`. Reboot did it.

Answer (score 11):

It maybe useful to add that if you're seeing this error message and you're not using some kind of restricted container based hosting (e.g. OpenVZ) then the problem maybe that the kernel is missing the nat modules. To check run:

```
modinfo iptable_nat
```

Which should print out the location of the module, if it prints an ERROR then you know that is your problem. There are also dependent modules like nf_nat which might be missing so you'll have to dig deeper if the iptable_nat module is there but fails. If it is missing you'll need to get another kernel and modules, or if you're rolling your own ensure that the kernel config contains `CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT=m` (for IPv4 NAT).

For info the relevant kernel module is usually found in one of these locations:

```
ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/netfilter/
ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/ipv4/netfilter/
```

And if you're running IPv6 also look here:

```
ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/ipv6/netfilter/
```

Comment: When I do `modinfo iptable_nat` I get `libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modinfo: ERROR: Module alias iptable_nat not found.
`. But I have no clue how to fix this. The version comes from `uname -r`

Comment: To regenerate the modules.dep.bin run: `sudo depmod` Then rerun the modinfo command.

Comment: I was already able to solve it. Thanks anyway: http://serverfault.com/questions/780980/error-could-not-open-directory-lib-modules-4-2-0-25-generic-no-such-file-or-d/782884

Answer (score 8):

Finaly, my service provider answered :

> This is a limitation of the virtualization system we  use (OpenVZ),
>   basic iptables rules are possible but not  those who use the nat
>   table.
>
> If this really is a problem, we can offer you to migrate to a  other
>   system virtualization (KVM) as we begin to offer  our customers.

SO I had to migrate my server to the new system...

Answer (score 6):

Short version :

run iptables on the host before to run it in the virtual server (I'm pretty sure this is some sort of LXC or OpenVZ container here).

Long version :

The problem is due to the fact that the ip_table module is loaded on demand. So, after a reboot, on any machine that does not have any iptables rules loaded at boot time, the ip_tables module is not loaded (no demand for the modules == the module is not loaded). Consequently, the LXC or OpenVZ containers cannot use iptables (since they share the host kernel but cannot modify which modules are loaded) until the host has somehow loaded the ip_tables module.

Answer (score 6):

iptalbes tool relies on a kernel module interacting with netfilter to control network traffic.

This error happens while iptalbes cannot found that module in kernel, so iptables suggest you to upgrade it :)

```
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

However in most cases it's just the module not added to kernel or being banned, try this command to check whether be banned:

```
cd /etc/modprobe.d/ && grep -nr iptable_nat
```

if the command shows any rule matched, such as `blacklist iptable_nat` or `install iptable_nat /bin/true`, delete it. Since iptalbes will cost some performance, it's not strange to ban it while not necessary.

If nothing found in blacklist, try add iptable-nat to the kernal manual:

```
modprobe iptable-nat
```

If all of above not works, you can consider really upgrade your kernal...

Comment: Saved my day, my system administrator put iptable-nat in /etc/modprobe.d/nf-blacklist.conf.

Answer (score 4):

The table names are case-sensitive so you should use lower-case nat instead of upper-case NAT.
For example;

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.1/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 2):

That solution from the official wiki:

```
vzctl set $CTID --netfilter full --save
```

https://openvz.org/VPN_via_the_TUN/TAP_device#Troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

"IP conntrack functionality has some negative impact on venet performance (uo to about 10%), so they better be disabled by default."
It's need for nat

https://serverfault.com/questions/593263/iptables-nat-does-not-exist

Answer (score 1):

On OpenSUSE 15.3 systemd log reported this error (insmod suggestion was unhelpful).

```
Feb 18 08:36:38 vagrant-openSUSE-Leap dockerd[20635]: iptables v1.6.2: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
```

**REBOOT fixed the problem**

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have set `IP_NF_NAT [=y]` when compiling the Linux kernel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you are running **puppet** it may set `/proc/sys/kernel/modules_disabled` to 1, inhibiting further module loading.
When the machine is reboot, it gets set back to 0, allowing for changes, such as loading the iptables modules. After a certain amount of time **puppet** will set it back to 1 to protect the system from kernel root kits.
 Therefore, whatever modules that we are going to need *should be loaded during or shortly after boot time*.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if you have a type in the name i.e. you type `NAT` instead of `nat`, you can get this error.

Answer (score -1):

check if tun/tap enabled:

```
cat /dev/net/tun
```

if ok will see something :

```
cat: /dev/net/tun: File descriptor in bad state
```

Comment: What does tun/tap have to do with the iptables NAT table?

Answer (score -3):

```
uname -av;
sudo apt install --reinstall (output from uname -av)
```