# SSHUTTLE throwing error 99 while connecting to static external IP (VPN) of GCP instance

Tags: python, linux, hadoop, google-cloud-platform

I have 4 Google cloud instances and I configured those as my hadoop cluster. I set static external IP to one of my instances to connect from my Linux machine (Windows subsystem for Linux). I tried to use **sshuttle** service to connect to that instance as **VPN** so that I can access another instances in my cluster through this VPN. sshuttle throwing error while connecting to my instance.

**[ERROR]**

```
sshuttle -r username@mystaticip 0.0.0.0/0 --ssh-cmd "ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine"
[local sudo] Password:
client: Connected.
iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
fatal: ['iptables', '-t', 'nat', '-nL'] returned 3
client: fatal: cleanup: ['sudo', '-p', '[local sudo] Password: ', 'PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '--', '/usr/bin/python3', '/usr/bin/sshuttle', '--method', 'auto', '--firewall'] returned 99
```

Comment: Two questions : 

Have you installed the iptables_nat module?

Could you run the sshuttle command with the -v (--verbose) option and provide us with the output?

Comment: @Alexandre I have disabled iptables and SELinux and I am a bit confused regarding iptables_nat module as I am not much aware of networking.

Comment: did you take a look on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983554/iptables-v1-4-14-cant-initialize-iptables-table-nat-table-does-not-exist-d)

Comment: @Alioua In that article, I am getting an **error** while using the command `sudo modprobe ip_tables.`      `sudo modprobe ip_tables
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-18362-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-18362-Microsoft
root@DESKTOP-C85ET3U:~#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, **Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Ubuntu** does not support `sshuttle`. It seems that the Ubuntu inside the WSL does not fully support the `iptables` commands sshuttle is calling.