# Issue in running docker on WSL2 Ubuntu 18 LTS

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have ubunto 18 LTS wsl2 on my windows 10 machine.

have installed the docker - please find below screenshot
[image: Docker Version and Starting service]

Now after starting the Docker service, I tried checking the docker info however encountered below error.

[image: Error while trying info]

I did some research and came across this post - [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678725/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-unix-var-run-docker-sock-is-the-docker)

as suggested in this, `systemctl start docker` also tried however got error as `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`

one more suggestion was to try out `sudo dockerd` - this resulted into below logs

```
INFO[2020-07-21T14:45:02.918374600+05:30] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2
WARN[2020-07-21T14:45:03.044702300+05:30] Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit
WARN[2020-07-21T14:45:03.046625300+05:30] Unable to find cpu cgroup in mounts
WARN[2020-07-21T14:45:03.049054700+05:30] Unable to find blkio cgroup in mounts
WARN[2020-07-21T14:45:03.051115500+05:30] Unable to find cpuset cgroup in mounts
WARN[2020-07-21T14:45:03.053056000+05:30] mountpoint for pids not found
INFO[2020-07-21T14:45:03.056254900+05:30] Loading containers: start.
WARN[2020-07-21T14:45:03.108913100+05:30] Running iptables --wait -t nat -L -n failed with message: `iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`, error: exit status 3
INFO[2020-07-21T14:45:03.522988800+05:30] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
INFO[2020-07-21T14:45:03.523923200+05:30] stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown  module=libcontainerd
INFO[2020-07-21T14:45:03.524034200+05:30] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

[image: sudo dockerd logs]

Moving on I googled above issue of iptable  and found [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983554](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983554/iptables-v1-4-14-cant-initialize-iptables-table-nat-table-does-not-exist-d/27129275) as instructed in forum , i tried `sudo modprobe ip_tables` which gave `modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-18362-Microsoft`

After all this I need some guidance if i am on right track.

Answer (score 0):

Running WSL2 Ubuntu as administrator from Windows solved this issue for me.
Thanks to [celinhoBruxo comment here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/767#issuecomment-620920628)

EDIT:

My issue was actually coming from that I tried to install directly WSL2 Ubuntu from Windows Store on a Windows version which doesn't support that (Version 1909).
I followed this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-manual) before installing again and everything worked fine without needing to run Ubuntu as admin from Windows.

Answer (score -2):

1.kill dockerd process (if no processes are found go to 2)
ps -aux | grep dockerd

kill -9 DOCKERD_PROCESS_ID

2.sudo dockerd &

Run dockerd successfully!

Comment: `dockerd` still needs `iptables` which does not exist, and this command will fail

Comment: I can't tell which is code and which is comment in support of the code.  That makes this answer not helpful.